# Import website to Mura cms

Tags: coldfusion, content-management-system, mura

I've a zip file containing all the necessary folder and content of Mura cms website. I've configured Mura cms 7.0 on localhost I want to import the website to localhost, How to Import it ?

Comment: Just follow the documentation on [Site Bundles](http://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/where-to-start/site-bundles/). First [How to Create/Export a Site Bundle](http://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/where-to-start/site-bundles/how-to-create-export-a-site-bundle/) and then [How to Deploy/Install a Site Bundle](http://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/where-to-start/site-bundles/how-to-deploy-install-a-site-bundle/)

Comment: when I add site it gives me Datasource verfication failed error.

Comment: That is a different issue. You must get your datasource configured and working before you can do any sort of import to Mura.Verification failure can be caused by any number of issues; cannot connect to the database server, wrong username, wrong password, wrong port, etc.